# Display or show monthly earnings using Stripe and Node.js

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, strip-tags

So I am trying to figure out how I can display to my connect users their monthly earnings so they can keep track of their profits. Example: March 1 - 31 _____________ $45,364.00 , April 1 - 30 _____________ $10,164.00

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Stripe API to list all of an account's [Balance Transactions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/list) and tally up the monthly amounts by [filtering by date range](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/list#balance_transaction_list-created).

Comment: When I use the Balance Transactions it returns an object... Can you please tell me what values I should pick out to tally up the monthly amounts?

Comment: You'd look at the `amount` value on each Balance Transaction and add them all up to find the total amount over a monthly period: https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object#balance_transaction_object-amount

Comment: Sorry to be a drag but you think you could give me an example???

Comment: You'd 1. List all Balance Transactions for the time specified 2. Loop over the returned Balance Transactions from step 1 3. Add up all the `amount` values of each Balance Transaction to get the monthly total.